# For loop or if-statement?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, for-loop

I've just started learning JavaScript and got a pretty basic question.

I'm going to create a function I call `printAnyRange()` that takes two arguments: `rangeStart` and `rangeStop`. I want this to return a string with all numbers comma-separated in the range.

If `rangeStart` is smaller than `rangeStop` it should call the function `printRange()`.

If `rangeStart` is greater than `rangeStop` it should call the function `printRangeReversed()`.

My question is, should I use a `for` loop to do this or would it be better with `if-else`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use if-else only to choose which method to call. For generating the range, you'll need to include a loop.

You can also follow basic recursion to avoid creating 3 different methods.

```
var printRange = function (num1, num2) {

    /* If num2 is smaller, call same function with arguments reversed */
    if (num1 > num2) return printRange (num2, num1);

    /* Otherwise, calculate the stuff you want */
    var result = [];
    for (num1; num1 <= num2; num1++) {
        result.push(num1);
    }

    return result.join(',');
};
```

This method will work for all the cases you described.

Comment: We can make this more elegant by replacing the for loop entirely with recursion but this should be good too for all pairs of numbers.

Comment: _“We can make this more elegant by replacing the for loop entirely with recursion”_ – introducing more complexity (and resource consumption) without any need or added benefits whatsoever doesn’t seem _“elegant”_ to me.

Comment: A recursive function especially when speaking to a mathematical situation like this is much more easier to read than a loop. At least that's what I have found. It may not work for everyone though.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you've outlined that it should call 1 of 2 possible functions there's really no alternative but to use an if/else statement. If you wanted to do away with the two function calls and instead use a for loop either forwards or in reverse then you'd still need an if (and arguably else) statement of some description to tie it all together.

```
if(rangeStart <= rangeStop)
{
    printRange(rangeStart, rangeStop);
}
else
{
    printReverseRange(rangeStart, rangeStop);
}
```

or

```
var start = rangeStart;
var stop = rangeStop;
var inc = 1;

if(rangeStart > rangeStop)
{
        var start = rangeStop;
        var stop = rangeStart;
        var inc = -1;
}

for(var i = start; inc == 1 ? start <= stop : start >= stop; i += inc)
{
   console.log(i);
}
```